# Basis of subspace that consists of polynomials that are divisible by $x^2+x+\overline{1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

We consider $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{\overline{0}, \overline{1}\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

To show that there is no $n\in \mathbb{Z}_2$ with $n^2=n+\overline{1}$, do we do the following?

For $n\equiv 0$ we have $n+1\equiv 1\not\equiv n^2$

For $n\equiv 1$ we have $n+1\equiv 0\not\equiv n^2$

That means that there is no $n\in \mathbb{Z}_2$ such that $n^2=n+\overline{1}$, right?

This also means that $x^2+x+1\equiv x^2-x-1$ has no root in $\mathbb{Z}_2$, right?

We consider the subspace $U\subseteq \mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ that consists of polynomials that are divisible by $x^2+x+\overline{1}$. How can we find a basis of $U$ ? Could you give me a hint?

We have that $U=\{p(x)\cdot (x^2+x+\overline{1})\}$, or not? But how can we find a basis with this information?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the space for which you want to find a basis is$$\{p(x)(x^2+x+1)\mid p(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_2[x]\}.$$So, a basis will be$$\{x^2+x+1,x(x^2+x+1),x^2(x^2+x+1),x^3(x^2+x+1),\dots\}$$

Comment: So this is not related with $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+\overline{1}\rangle$ is it?

Comment: It is related in the sense that $\langle x^2+x+1\rangle=U$. But $\dim\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle=2$.

Comment: Ahh ok!! As for $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/\langle x^2+x+1\rangle$ it is the set of the remainders of the division of the polynomials of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ and $ x^2+x+1$ or not? How would we find in this case a basis?

Comment: I made a mistake: the dimension is $4$, not $2$. And a basis will be$$\{\langle x^2+x+1\rangle,1+\langle x^2+x+1\rangle,x+\langle x^2+x+1\rangle,x+1+\langle x^2+x+1\rangle\}.$$

Comment: Could you explain to me why this is a basis for $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/U$ ? How do we find that?

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $h(x)=x^2+x+1$ has no root in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ because $h(0)=1$ and $h(1)=1$. (Use overlines if you so prefer.)

The $\mathbb{Z}_2$-linear map
$$
\varphi\colon\mathbb{Z}_2[x]\to U,\qquad \varphi(f)=fh
$$
is bijective. So it transforms a basis in a basis. A basis of the domain is $\{1,x,x^2,\dotsc\}$.

Comment: That means that $\phi \left (\{1,x,x^2,\dotsc\}\right )=\{1\cdot h \ , \ x\cdot h \ , \ x^2\cdot h \ , \ \dotsc\}$ is a basis, correct?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, Just apply $\varphi$ to each element of the basis.

Comment: Ok, I got it!! Could you explain to me also how to find a basis for $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/U$ ? $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/U$ is the set of remainders of the division of a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ by $x^2+x+1$, or not?

Comment: @MaryStar A basis is $\{1+U,x+U\}$. It is *always* true that if $U=(h(x))$ and $h$ has degree $n>0$, then a basis for $F[x]/U$ ($F$ a field) is $\{1+U,x+U,\dots,x^{n-1}+U\}$. It's irrelevant whether $h$ is irreducible or not; irreducibility yields that $F[x]/U$ is a field.

Comment: Is this like that because the degree of the rermainder must be smaller than that of $x^2+x+1$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, that's it. And it's easy to show that $\{1+U,x+U\}$ is linearly independent.